# MySQL: adding current year as a default value for a field 'year'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

I have the following table in MySQL (version 5):

```
id     int(10)       UNSIGNED             No    auto_increment              
year   varchar(4)    latin1_swedish_ci    No             
title  varchar(250)  latin1_swedish_ci    Yes   NULL         
body   text          latin1_swedish_ci    Yes   NULL
```

And I want the db to auto add the current year on insert, I've tried the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `tips` CHANGE `year` `year` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT year(now())
```

But it gives the following error:

```
1067 - Invalid default value for 'year'
```

What can I do to get this functionality? Thanks in advance!

Comment: having columns with the same name as a datatype is usually a really BAD idea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The DEFAULT value  clause in a data
>   type specification indicates a default
>   value for a column. With one
>   exception, the default value must be a
>   constant; it cannot be a function or
>   an expression. This means, for
>   example, that you cannot set the
>   default for a date column to be the
>   value of a function such as NOW() or
>   CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that
>   you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as
>   the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

[-- MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

You can, however, write a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that sets the value.  I wish I could help, but I'm not really familiar with writing stored procedures in MySQL.

I think this would work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_year
BEFORE INSERT ON tips
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.year = YEAR(NOW());
```

Answer (score 8):

The following should work:

```
ALTER TABLE tips MODIFY COLUMN year YEAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Please see [Year Data Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html) for further information.

So, I tested this once I got access and it doesn't work. As another poster pointed out CURRENT_TIMESTAMP only works on the [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) data type.

Is there a specific problem with storing a complete time stamp and then only using the year in your code? If not, then I would recommend storing this value as a timestamp.

Your other option would be to create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER example_trigger AFTER INSERT ON tips
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE tips SET year = YEAR(NOW()) WHERE tip_id = NEW.tip_id
END;
```

Otherwise, assign this value to the INSERT statement from within your code.

The best solution in your case will depend entirely on the circumstances surrounding your particular application.

Comment: Beautiful, I was looking for exactly the same thing today!

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a fairly old post, but for others still finding this via search engines. As of MySQL 8.0.13, you can use [expressions as column defaults](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit). So, your original alter statement is valid. You just need to wrap it in parentheses like so. I would also suggest to use the `YEAR` [data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) instead of varchar, it contains validation and built-in conversions; like `10` will be converted to `2010` etc...

```
ALTER TABLE `tips`
    CHANGE `year` `year` YEAR NOT NULL DEFAULT (YEAR(CURDATE()));
```