# how to set Year Datatype in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, types, phpmyadmin

I can't understand  what wrong in this sql statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl_car_model_year_rate
SET car_model_id =4,
FROM =2008,
TO =2011,
with_driver =1,
per_day =1000,
ten_days =10000,
twenty_days =20000,
thirty_days =30000,
image =  '1303166512test.jpg',
created_at = NOW( ) ,
created_by =1
```

Datatype

```
car_model_id    int(11) 
image   text        
from    year(4)
to  year(4)
with_driver tinyint(1)          
per_day int(11) 
ten_days    int(11) 
twenty_days int(11)
thirty_days int(11)
created_at datetime 
created_by int(11)
```

Error Messsage

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from  =2008, to   =2011, with_driver =1, per_day  =1000, ten_days =10000,     twenty' at line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you change your code to:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_car_model_year_rate SET car_model_id =4,
`FROM` =2008,
`TO` =2011,
with_driver =1,
per_day =1000,
ten_days =10000,
twenty_days =20000,
thirty_days =30000,
image =  '1303166512test.jpg',
created_at = NOW( ) ,
created_by =1
```

It will work.
If you add your field and/or table names in backticks "`" then you can use just about any name for them.

**Reason for failure**
`FROM` is a reserved word (as in `select *`**`FROM`**`tablename`)
You are confusing MySQL by using `FROM` as a column name *(`select * FROM FROM WHERE FROM = AND`)*

**My Recommendation**
Do not use reserved words for fieldnames.
Change the column name from `FROM` to `YearFrom` or `StartYear`
and from `TO` to `YearTo` or `EndYear`.

Using reserved words as column names is just plain confusing and adding backticks around everything just makes stuff hard to read and ugly and whilst still being confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a reserved word for a column name.

> Certain words such as SELECT, DELETE,
>   or BIGINT are reserved and require
>   special treatment for use as
>   identifiers such as table and column
>   names. This may also be true for the
>   names of built-in functions.
>
> Reserved words are permitted as
>   identifiers if you quote them as
>   described in [Section 8.2, “Schema
>   Object Names”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html):

For a more detailed list of reserved words, including differences between versions, see [Reserved Words in MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords.html#mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

TO and FROM are reserved words you should put it in a single qoute like 'FROM', 'TO'.

and remember avoid using reserved words for columns while generating your tables see the below link for complete reference for the reserved words for mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example correct use of year field in MySQL:

[MySQL: adding current year as a default value for a field 'year'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301937/mysql-adding-current-year-as-a-default-value-for-a-field-year)